# Constantly high traffic in local network

Tags: networking

I encountered constantly high traffic (~25Mb/s) in all computers in my company office network (image below).

[image: Traffic in network]

It happened after I introduced a VOIP phone system. The VOIP shared same network as computers. I tried to contact my VOIP phone vendor but they insisted the setting is correct and the machine will not making these broadcast traffic so it is not their problem.

I turned to wireshark and seems that a lot of packets are broadcast packets from 239.255.255.250

resources monitor:
[image: resources monitor]

wireshark:
[image: wireshark]

The problem did go away when I unplug the VOIP machine from network. Anything i can do on the switch port so that I can use my VOIP phone without these annoying traffic?

Comment: That's multicast, no broadcast - the source IP address is indicated, so you know the source. Most likely it's a misconfiguration. You should also consider separating VoIP traffic in its own VLAN, that would also limit the broadcast/multicast domain.

Comment: thanks for your reply, 192.168.22.5 is my PC so I think the situation is all my office computers response to multicast request from somewhere. The network usage show the traffic is "receiving" instead of "send". Is it possible to block multicast traffic of switch port that connect VOIP machine?

Comment: You're only showing that direction, no incoming traffic from the switch - we don't know what that is. It's not too likely yet possible that SSDP from the SIP gateway ("VoIP machine") is causing constant messaging between PC clients and the gateway - it's best to isolate VoIP in its own VLAN. With a meaningful capture from your PC the vendor really should be able to help you though.

Comment: What about implementing qos to shape the traffic.